# css gurus: how to swap too spans (inline-block, no fixed width)?

Tags: css, html, swap

I have too spans

```
<span class="in_bl right">Right</span>
<span class="in_bl left">Left</span>
```

With the help of css user should see "Left Right".

In the html "Right" should go before "Left", so that strip_tags() would result in "Right Left".

Here is my attempt with floating http://jsfiddle.net/2SGCb/12/ but float right causes problem in IE: parent expands to the full available width.

Any suggestions how to swap inline-block spans are welcome.
Expected output is http://jsfiddle.net/2SGCb/12/ to look ok in all browsers ("Start Left Right End"), for now that example is not working in IE.

Comment: why are you using this: `*display: inline;`

Comment: I think one of the browsers did not render inline-block correctly, so I added this fix.

Answer (score 0):

try this css apply to your work

```
.left {
   background: #999; float: left; height: 100%; width: auto;
}

.right {
   background: #666; height: 100%;
}
```

hope it helped